# AjaxControlToolKit HTMLExtender ImageUpload works on localhost, not server

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmlextensions

So, I've looked over everyone's questions, and I can't seem to find a reliable answer. I find it hard to believe that AjaxControlToolKit would release an item that couldn't work on a public facing website. So here's my question.

My AjaxControlToolKit HTMLExtender ImageUpload function works SWIMMINGLY on my localhost when I test, but the moment I test on the live address (which is behind a login in a custom CMS), I can't get the file to post to the server. I have the same .dlls, the same web.config, the same everything, but I get this response in Chrome Inspector:

> Uncaught error raising upload complete event and start new upload
>         t.onreadystatechange

Any suggestions on where to start?